# Двойная функция

Tags: php

Если мы делаем вот так:

```
if($rov['chislo_1']&&$row['chislo_2'] > 0 ){
```

то Else будет выполняться только тогда когда эти две переменные будут ниже нуля , а как сделать вот  так :

```
if($rov['chislo_1'] или $row['chislo_2'] > 0 ){
```

Разделить их не проходит ! Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($rov['chislo_1'] || $row['chislo_2'] > 0 )
```

Comment: если имеется ввиду что если хотя бы одно число больше нуля, то
  if($rov['chislo_1']>0 || $row['chislo_2'] > 0 )

Comment: да все правильно, спасибо =)